# Text could not be parsed at index 33

Tags: android, datetime, threetenbp

I am working on ThreeTenABP library to parse date and time. However, it is crashing. API I consume sends DateTime like;

> 2018-10-20T14:27:47.3949709+03:00

This is the way I try to parse;

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                .toFormatter();

Timber.d(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-20T14:27:47.3949709+03:00", formatter).toString());
```

I am getting below error:

> Text '2018-10-20T14:27:47.3949709+03:00' could not be parsed at index
>   33

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can improve your question by replacing `Timer.d()` with `System.out.println()` or `Log.d`, there is no need to pull a third-party library into this. Best provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks, @leonardkraemer, sorry this code was taken from a corporate project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation of the error message:**

`2018-10-20T14:27:47.3949709+03:00` is 33 chars long, therefore

> Text '2018-10-20T14:27:47.3949709+03:00' could not be parsed at index 33

means it expected a 34th char which is not there (it's 0 indexed).

**Problem**

The way you defined the `Formatter` it would accept  2018-10-20T14:27:47.3949709+03:002018-10-20`

**Solution:**

To overcome this you can either drop the `.append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Or define a `Formatter` that accepts both formats with [`startOptional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#optionalStart--) and `endOptional`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .optionalStart()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)
    .optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"))
    .optionalEnd().toFormatter();
```

You can see the example working at https://ideone.com/RDVHYG

*Side note*: "yyyy-MM-dd" does  not yield enough information for a `LocalDateTime` therefore I added "HH:mm"

Comment: Hi @leonardkraemer

I tried your solution however it threw below error:

Text '2018-10-24T16:37:32.693Z' could not be parsed at index 2

Comment: Dont mind the `java.time` imports I tried it on android with actual ThreeTenABP

Comment: Hi @leonardkraemer, Yeah it works. You saved my day! Thanks ahead. I accepted the answer :) Good day!

Comment: Hi @leonardkraemer,

Last question :) Whatever I have any pattern, it always gives me same output. For instance, I set a pattern like "dd MM yyyy EEEE" and I am expecting an output

20 October 2018 Wednesday but it always give 2018-10-20